# What database type do I need to find similarities between lists?

Tags: database, search

I have a collection of lists. Each list contains multiple items with an identifier and a numeric value. Something like cake recipes.
I want to compare all the different user recipes, to find relations between flour and sugar, or number of eggs and quantity of vanilla extract.

I have the recipes in JSON format in a document DB. something like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "roast",
        "ingredients": [
            { "quantity": "1000", "type": "red Meat" },
            { "quantity": "10", "type": "gravy mix" },
            { "quantity": "10", "type": "dried Italian salad dressing mix" }
            { "quantity": "100", "type": "water" }
        ],
        "steps": [...],
        "score": 4.1
    },
    {
        "name": "plain cookies",
        "ingredients": [
            { "quantity": "400", "type": "flour" },
            { "quantity": "400", "type": "sugar" },
            { "quantity": "2", "type": "eggs" }
            { "quantity": "100", "type": "oil" }
        ],
        "steps": [...],
        "score": 3.1
    },
    {
        "name": "bread",
        "ingredients": [
            { "quantity": "1000", "type": "flour" },
            { "quantity": "50", "type": "sugar" },
            { "quantity": "3", "type": "eggs" }
            { "quantity": "100", "type": "oil" }
        ],
        "steps": [...],
        "score": 4.3
    }
]
```

example queries:

- find highest scoring recipes with "flour" and "egg"
- what is the most popular number if eggs used with 1000 flour?

I don't think that running a query comparing recipe ingredients would be very efficient.
do I need to normalize the data? or would a graph DB be the better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Use cases where the structure is pretty well defined and you already know what type of queries you will be executing a Relational DB seems to be the best bet.

In the above example you can create 2 tables:

- Recipe:

  CREATE TABLE Recipe (Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL, Name Varchar(256), Score Decimal(1,1))
- Ingredients:

  CREATE TABLE Ingredients (Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL, Type Varchar(256), Quantity INT NOT NULL, RecipeId INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Recipe(Id))

Your queries can be executed as

- Find highest scoring recipes with "flour" and "egg"

  SELECT * FROM Recipe R INNER JOIN Ingredients I ON I.RecipeId = R.Id Where I.Type = 'flour' Or I.Type = 'egg' Order by R.Score Desc
- What is the most popular number of eggs used with 1000 flour?

  SELECT Count(Quantity), Quantity FROM Ingredients Where Type = 'egg' AND RecipeId IN (SELECT RecipeId From Ingredients Where Type = 'flour' AND Quantity = 1000) GROUP BY Quantity ORDER BY Count(Quantity) Desc

In addition to above you can add indexes to make the queries run faster.